# Drupal 7 | Import CSV, row by row, into custom table

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Assuming I have a CSV like this:

```
value1,value2
value1,value2
```

and a table with two columns

```
column1|column2
```

how can I programatically import the CSV into the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@erier's answer is really good and will get the job done.

As the question is tagged with Drupal 7 I thought I would submit a Drupal custom module method, adapting @erier's answer and prettifying it.

For the basics of a custom module, you can see this simple example.

```
function custom_module_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['csv_upload'] = array(
    '#type' => 'file',
    '#title' => t('Choose a file'),
    '#title_display' => 'invisible',
    '#size' => 22,
    '#upload_validators' => array('file_clean_name' => array()),
  );
  $form['upload'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Upload',
  );
}

function custom_module_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  $validators = array('file_validate_extensions' => array('csv'));

  // Check for a new uploaded file.
  $file = file_save_upload('csv_upload', $validators);
  //$file = $form_state['values']['csv_upload'];

  if (isset($file)) {
    // File upload was attempted.
    if ($file) {
      // Put the temporary file in form_values so we can save it on submit.
      $form_state['values']['csv_upload_file'] = $file;
    }
    else {
      // File upload failed.
      form_set_error('csv_upload', t('The file could not be uploaded.'));
    }
  }
}

function custom_module_submit($form, &$form_state) {

    $file = $form_state['values']['csv_upload_file'];
    $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
    $file->filename = str_replace(' ', '_', $file->filename);
    file_save($file);

    $csv_file = file_load($file->fid);
    $file = fopen($csv_file->uri, "r");


    while(! feof($file))
      {
      $customer = fgetcsv($file));
      db_insert('your_db_table')
        ->fields(array(
            'column1' => $customer[0],
            'column2' => $customer[1]
        ))
        ->execute();
      }

    fclose($file);

    drupal_set_message('CSV data added to the database');
}

function file_clean_name($file) {
  $file->filename = str_replace(' ', '_', $file->filename);
}
```

That is assuming your question was about a database table.

If you meant into an html table, you can adapt the submit function after `$csv_file = file_load($file->fid);` like this:

```
$headers = array('column 1', 'column 2');
$rows = array();

$file = fopen("contacts.csv","r");

while(! feof($file))
  {
  $customer = fgetcsv($file));
  $rows[] = array($customer[0], $customer[1]);
  }

fclose($file);

return theme('table', array('header' => $headers, 'rows' => $rows);
```

Or adapt the two by adding the data to the database and displaying to the screen without a second database hit.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I've come up with - I'm no PHP expert - and it doesn't seem pretty - but it works!

```
$handle = fopen('/path/to/file/filename.csv', 'r');
$row = fgetcsv($handle);

for ($e = 0; $row = fgetcsv($handle); $e++) {
    $record = array();

    foreach ($row as $field) {
        $record[] = $field;
    }

    db_insert('your_db_table')
    ->fields(array(
        'column1' => $record[0],
        'column2' => $record[1]
    ))
    ->execute();
}

fclose($handle);
```

The table will then look like this:

```
column1|column2
---------------
 value1|value2
 value1|value2
```

Answer (score 0):

This module may help you
https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/draenen/2442165
It requires Feeds but it extends it to work with custom tables (non drupal entities)